# Google Drive API Service Account authentication to upload and insert an image file to into copied doc using Python

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

Google Drive API docs are not super great at helping determine best way to authenticate using a service account that I can then upload a .png file to the Drive. My end goal it so upload a .png file, copy a template doc, batch update that doc using text replace, and insert the newly uploaded .png image into that doc.

Sample code below:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

def credentials_from_file():
  credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    os.getenv('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE'), 
    scopes=os.getenv('SCOPES')
  )
  drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
  return drive_service

def google_upload(drive_service, metadata_name, parents, permissions, file_path, mime_type):
  file_metadata = {'kind':'drive#file', 'name':metadata_name, 'parents':parents, 'permissions':permissions}
  media = MediaFileUpload(file_path, mimetype=mime_type)
  file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id', supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
  print('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
```

Implementation of Code

```
credentials = credentials_from_file()
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

metadata_name = custom_variables_png_table_img
parents = ['xxxx']
permissions = [{'kind':'drive#permission', 'emailAddress':os.getenv('EMAIL_ACCOUNT'), 'role':'owner'}]
file_path = custom_variables_png_table_img
mime_type = 'image/png'
google_upload(drive_service, metadata_name, parents, permissions, file_path, mime_type)
```

## EDIT:

Looks like I forgot to actually write was the problem is. It's two fold.

1. I keep getting 2 errors when trying to run the `google_upload()` function which looks like an authentication error with the service account.

> Error #1: `jwt_grant access_token = response_data["access_token"] KeyError: 'access_token'`

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Error #2: `google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('No access token in response.', {'id_token': 'xxx'})`

2. Permissions being properly set on the recently uploaded image file.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: Ask away. What're your questions?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I cannot understand about your current issue from your question. So I asked about the detail of it.

Comment: What is the proper way to authenticate a service account to be able to upload a .png image to drive using the API, and then set the correct permissions for that new file?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58080962

Comment: What is your actual problem? What *is/isn't* your code doing compared to what you expect? What happens when `google_upload` is called?

Comment: Also - are you trying to upload the file to *your* Drive, or the service account's Drive?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, thank you for point that out. In my haste to get this posted while running out the door, forgot that minor part. I updated my description above. Uploads are to a folder on my drive that I have shared with the service account. I do know I need to update permissions but have had a hard time finding the right, most recent/up to date way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using currently seams to be the same as what I have seen before.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = '<REPLACE_WITH_JSON_FILE_PATH_TO_FILE>'



def initialize_drive():
  """Initializes an Google Drive API V3 service object.

  Returns:
    An authorized Google Drive API V3 service object.
  """
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

  # Build the service object.
  driveService = build('drive', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

  return driveService
```

You haven't mentioned what is wrong with your code however i can make a few guesses.

The thing is that you mention you want to upload an image and the insert it into a document.  You need to remember that the Google drive api is just a file storage api it can do more then that store files.

When you upload the file using the service account you need to remember that the service account is not you.  So when you are uploading this file to this directory `parents = ['xxxx']` where ever that directory is, either on the service accounts drive account or if this directory is one of your persona directories which you have shared with the service account.  You may not have permissions to see this file.

By calling [permissions create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) after uploading your file you can grant your own personal account permissions to access the file as well.

As for adding the image to a document.  well the only way google can help you with that is if it is a Google doc type document.  Then you would need to go though the [Google docs api](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest) which would then give you access to add things programmaticlly to a document.   I haven't used this API much so im not sure if it has the ability to add images to a document.

You should be able to use the google docs api with your service account you will just need to create a docs service using the same creds you already have from google drive.

```
 service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment @DaImTo. I updated my question/issue above with the two errors/issues I am seeing. Everything you said here makes sense. I have got the updating a document part with plain text figured out and know how to figure out adding the image, if I can get the permissions and access to the image correct. If you are able to, please take a look at the updated edit to the original question for further clarification.

Comment: Response to number 1: Mind giveing us a print out of what you have in os.getenv('SCOPES')   Response to number 2:  Remember you cant set the permissions on the file in the upload call.  You need to set the permissions on the file after its been uploaded.  (its a feature from google)

Comment: #1: SCOPES output: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
#2: Got that and adjusted the code appropriately.

Comment: scopes=os.getenv('SCOPES')   <-- dump the scopes=

Comment: Just did that and got a new error:
credentials=service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(os.getenv('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE'), os.getenv('SCOPES'))
TypeError: from_service_account_file() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Sounds like one of them isnt set.  Want to try and do it without the env vars and hard code this just to test there isnt a problem with your scopes or with the path to the key file.