# How to create a Google Doc with regular text as the body?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm in the process of taking information stored in a Google Sheet and trying to neatly format it on a Google Doc. I'm using the Google Docs API [here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents), but I'm not following how to properly use the 'body:' part of the JSON representation.

For the sake of simplicity, how would you create a new document with the title "Test" and the body just saying "Hello world!". If needed, I'm using Python 3.7.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- From `how would you create a new document with the title "Test" and the body just saying "Hello world!".`, I understood that you want to upload a text of `Hello world!` as new Google Document using python.

#### Issue and workaround:

I think that in this case, I would like to propose to use Drive API. Because in the current stage, when Google Docs API is used, 2 API calls are required to be used as follows, because the method of `documents.create` cannot include the text body.

1. Create new Google Document using the method of `documents.create`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create)
2. Upload the text using the method of `documents.batchUpdate`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)

So, in this answer, I would like to propose to use the method of `Files: create` in Drive API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) When this method is used, your goal can be achieved by one API call.

The sample script using googleapis for python is as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this case, please use the authorization script of [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python). In this case, please use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` as the scope.

```
drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
text = 'Hello world!'
media = MediaIoBaseUpload(io.BytesIO(text.encode('utf-8')), mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)
file_metadata = {"name": "Test", "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document"}
file = drive.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media).execute()
print(file)
```

- When above script is run, new Google Document with the filename of `Test` is created, and the body has the text of `Hello world!`.
- In this case, `from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseUpload` is also used.

#### Note:

- If you are required to use Google Docs API, you can also use the following script. In this case, the result is the same with above sample script.

  ```
    docs = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    text = 'Hello world!'
    res1 = docs.documents().create(body={"title": "Test"}).execute()
    requests = [{"insertText": {"location": {"index": 1}, "text": text}}]
    res2 = docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=res1.get('documentId'), body={"requests": requests}).execute()
    print(res2)
  ```

#### References:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Method: documents.create](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create)
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thank you, that is a very thorough answer to my question. One last thing, how would I give editor permission access to specific users as it seems only the Google Service account can access this file

Comment: @Tucker Thank you for replying. About your additional question of `how would I give editor permission access to specific users as it seems only the Google Service account can access this file`, in this case, I think that the method of "Permissions: create" can be used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) The sample script can be seen at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58088998/7108653 If this was not the answer you expect, I apologize.